# is this fencing legal?

Tags: installation

My neighbor already had a wooden privacy fence up. New neighbor's bought the home and put up a new privacy fence w/o taking down the old one. Basically a double privacy fence. Is that legal?

Comment: It'd be entirely up to your local codes. Check with the city/county and ask.

Comment: They probably thought it was yours. Ask them if it can be taken it down.

Comment: As noted by @DA01, this depends on lot on local legislation in the US. In many other countries, the sticking point would be if they are staying within their terrain, or trespassing on yours.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bylaw question not a home improvement/diy question

Comment: @ALANWARD true, though in many parts of the US, you also often have to ensure that the 'good side' of the fence faces out. Having two fences may not be considered 'good' and they may make them take one down even if it's entirely within their property lines.

Comment: @DA01 OK, so we're definitely back to local by-laws.

Comment: The more I think on it, the more I suspect that the fence was built on your property by the prior neighbor, either from ignorance or as a deliberate grab attempt under adverse possession law (if applicable), and the new owners likely got an accurate survey which showed it to be your fence, so they put up their own fence. Check near the corners on the other side of the fence and see if there are any survey/property markers that might have been recently exposed/painted as part of the real estate transaction. Consider getting an accurate survey yourself, if there seems to be any room for doubt.

Answer (score 2):

As Alan Ward says, it depends on your local jurisdiction.

In the UK, for example, it would be perfectly legal as long as it is on their land - in fact it is quite common in certain circumstances, for example if someone lives next to an industrial unit with a big metal security fence, they might put up a nicer-looking wooden one to hide the unsightly metal one.